# In org-mode, how to reference the value of a property in another property?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-properties

For example, when exporting, the `#+title` property is taken as the title of the document, which will show as the heading in, for example, a latex pdf. Ideally I would like the `#+title` value to also be used as the filename as well.

Right now I have to do this:

```
#+title: My Title
#+export_file_name: My Title
```

Is there any way I can do something like this:

```
#+title: My Title
#+export_file_name: (#+title)
```

Really the goal is to only have to write the title once per document, and have it be used in multiple property values.

I have tried using macros, but they did not work, it will try to export to `{{{mymacro}}}.pdf` and fail.

Comment: In general, you cannot: property values are strings and are not parsed at all, so Org mode does not know what's in them. `#+title:` is not really a property: it's a keyword and *some* keywords (e.g. `#+title:`) are parsed  and macro expansion is performed on them. Unfortunately, `#+export_file_name:` is not one of them. I get the feeling that what is parsed and what is not is more-or-less an accident of history. This area could use some rationalization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write an interactive Elisp function asking you to input a value when triggered. Once the value is input, the function will then write the following two lines at the beginning of your org document:

```
#+title: input value
#+export_file_name: input value
```